# how to remove duplicates from a comma seperated string in sql server

Tags: sql-server

how to  remove duplicate values from the comma seperated string in sql server. Without using functions

```
 Declare @data varchar(max) = '34.22,768.55,34.22,123.34,12,999.0,999.0'
```

My expected result should be

```
34.22,768.55,123.34,12,999.0
```

i tried this query but it doesn't remove duplicates from the variable.

```
Declare @data varchar(max) = '34.22,768.55,34.22,123.34,12,999.0,999.0'
set @data= (select '' + cast(cast('<d>'+replace(@data, ', ',',</d><d>')+'</d>'  as xml).query('distinct-values(/d)') as varchar(max)) +'')
```

Comment: What is your reason for not wanting to use a Function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Please try this -**

```
DECLARE @x AS XML=''
Declare @finalstring varchar(max) = ''
DECLARE @Param AS VARCHAR(100) = '34.22,768.55,34.22,123.34,12,999.0,999.0'
SET @x = CAST('<A>'+ REPLACE(@Param,',','</A><A>')+ '</A>' AS XML)
select @finalstring = @finalstring + value + ',' from ( 
SELECT t.value('.', 'VARCHAR(10)') Value FROM @x.nodes('/A') AS x(t))p
GROUP BY value
PRINT SUBSTRING(@finalstring,0,LEN(@finalstring))
```

**OUTPUT**

12,123.34,34.22,768.55,999.0

**For sql 2016+**

```
Declare @data varchar(max) = '34.22,768.55,34.22,123.34,12,999.0,999.0'
Declare @finalstring varchar(max) = ''
select @finalstring = @finalstring + value + ',' from string_split(@data,',')
GROUP BY value
PRINT SUBSTRING(@finalstring,0,LEN(@finalstring))
```

**OUTPUT**

12,123.34,34.22,768.55,999.0

Comment: The thing is, the OP stated *"Without using functions"*. You're using the `STRING_SPLIT` function here. I'd sill, however, love to know why the OP doesn't want to use one.

Comment: Yes you are correct don't know why not to use the functions for this. STRING_SPLIT is the best method to split the strings.

Comment: I like this answer for 2016+

Comment: Can this act as a computed column in 2016+?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Declare @data varchar(max) = '34.22,768.55,34.22,123.34,12,999.0,999.0'

SELECT STUFF(
(
    SELECT DISTINCT ',' + UniqNum FROM
    (
        SELECT CAST('<d>'+replace(@data, ',','</d><d>')+'</d>' AS XML) AS numberXml
    ) as t1
    CROSS APPLY 
    (
     SELECT my_Data.D.value('.','varchar(50)') as UniqNum
     FROM t1.numberXml.nodes('d') as my_Data(D)
    ) t2
    FOR XML PATH('')
), 1, 1, '')
```

**Result**

```
UniqNumber
---------------------------
12,123.34,34.22,768.55,999.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
Declare @data varchar(max) = '34.22,768.55,34.22,123.34,12,999.0,999.0'

 ;WITH CTE
 AS
 (
    SELECT
        MyStr = SUBSTRING(@data,CHARINDEX(',',@Data)+1,LEN(@data)),
        Val = SUBSTRING(@data,1,CHARINDEX(',',@data)-1)

    UNION ALL

    SELECT
        MyStr = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',',MyStr)>0
                        THEN SUBSTRING(MyStr,CHARINDEX(',',MyStr)+1,LEN(MyStr))
                    ELSE NULL END,
        Val = CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(',',MyStr)>0
                        THEN SUBSTRING(MyStr,1,CHARINDEX(',',MyStr)-1)
                    ELSE MyStr END
        FROM CTE
            WHERE ISNULL(REPLACE(MyStr,',',''),'')<>''
 )
 SELECT
    Val = SUBSTRING(List,1,LEN(List)-1)
    FROM
     (
     SELECT
        DISTINCT Val+','
        FROM CTE
            WHERE ISNULL(MyStr ,'')<>''
            FOR XML PATH('')
    )Q(List)
```

My Result

```
12,123.34,34.22,768.55,999.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Just an another simple way of doing it.

```
Declare @data Nvarchar(max) = N'34.22,768.55,34.22,123.34,12,999.0,999.0'
     , @data2 Nvarchar(max)='';
SELECT @data = N'SELECT @DATA_DIST= @DATA_DIST+VAL+'','' 
     FROM (SELECT '''+replace(@data,',',''' AS VAL UNION SELECT ''')+''')A';
EXECUTE sp_executesql @data,N'@DATA_DIST varchar(MAX) OUTPUT',@DATA_DIST=@data2 OUTPUT;
SELECT LEFT(@data2,LEN(@data2)-1);
```

**Result:**

> 12,123.34,34.22,768.55,999.0